# Mapping a Remote Network Drive

Tags: nas, network-drive

I use Windows 8.1, and through its "Map a Network Drive" functionality, I access various folders inside my LAN-connected NAS. I like this feature because it allows me to elegantly browse contents on my NAS with all the benefits of the Windows File Explorer, that is comfortable copies, moves, renames etc.

Question is, how can I map a network drive for the same folders of the same NAS, but when I'm outside my LAN? (or alternatively, when I'm in my LAN, access any other NAS which is remote).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are two options - either the Windows server provides access to its shares across the internet (a bad idea) or you use a VPN.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on the former? How do I configure that up? Thanks.

Comment: You port forward tcp/445 on your internet router to the NAS hosting the share.  But seriously, don't do this unless you fully understand the risks.

Comment: Could you please explain about the risks?